# How do I install modules using a module?

Tags: installation

I wanted to install few modules when my module is installed. How can this be achieved?

I am creating a module which requires few other modules to be installed. I want to install them when my main module is installed.

I have placed all those module folders inside one main folder, and I want to create an install file to install those modules when this main install file is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in addition to kiamlaluno's (correct) answer, if you want to get stuck in and do-it-yourself you can use the core [`module_enable`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_enable/7) function, perhaps in your module's [`hook_enable()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7) function:

```
function MYMODULE_enable() {
  $modules = array('module_1', 'module_2');
  module_enable($modules);
}
```

The code is purely for demonstration purposes, I wouldn't actually recommend using it; if you want to make sure certain modules are enabled along with yours, the safest way is to use `dependencies[]` in your .info file as has already been described.

Comment: I have over 25 modules to be installed and I dont want the user to do this that tiring job. I think your suggestion is a good idea and I am going to try that.

Comment: Thank you very much.. your solution suites me better.. :)

Answer (score 2):

If there are modules from which your module depends, your module should declare them as dependencies, in its .info file. Supposing that your module is my_secret_module.module, and it depends from first_module, and second_module, my_secret_module.info should contain the following lines.

```
// Drupal 5
dependencies = first_module second_module

// Drupal 6, Drupal 7, and next releases
dependencies[] = first_module
dependencies[] = second_module
```

In this way, your module cannot be enabled of the other modules are not enabled too.

Comment: But I dont want to use dependencies. I want to install the modules myself. I have over 25 dependencies and I dont want the user to install all 25 dependencies individually as it is tiring.

Comment: @DrupalDeveloper Your users won't have to install the modules manually, they just need to enable your module, and all of the dependencies will be installed along with it (after a single confirmation page)